# A co worker was suspended and it was broadcasted over walkie talkie is telling him about the transmission a breach?

Tags: work-environment, ethics

My co worker was in the office with administration. I was unaware of ALL proceedings of this meeting. They had put him on suspension and for whatever reason the meeting was being broadcasted via walkie talkie. 
Now I heard the transmission but could not clearly make a distinction as to what it pertained to.

He came out of the office and looked upset and I said was that you on the radio cursing. There was cursing and screaming.

I am in contact with said employee. Is discussing any of this a breach of confidentiality?

Nothing was told to me as far as what was going on and what could or could not be disclosed about it. I was given 90 days probation for the matter. Am I in the wrong?

Comment: I would hazard a guess your probation was for listening to a private meeting, and then talking to the employee about the contents of said private meeting, when the meeting contents were not for you to know. You should know not to listen to a meeting unless you know it is relevant to you.

Comment: @clairebones As far as I understand, he didn't try to eavesdrop, it was them who broadcasted it on an open channel for no reason… if it was really so, I don't see how could they complain.

Comment: There are way too many legal implications, here.  If you are in the U.S., both FCC regulations and federal/state wiretapping laws may have been broken.  It even makes a difference if you are an emergency services worker or not.  In any event, any disclosure not absolutely required by your job would be inappropriate.  The correct action would have been to interrupt their meeting and mention to your admins that they were broadcasting.  No other discussions are appropriate.

Comment: What exactly was the reason you were given for the 90 days probation?

Comment: If they were the ones broadcasting the meeting, it sounds like they were the ones violating your coworker's privacy, not you.

Answer (score 10):

Whoa, there's a lot of issues there. Let's try to break this down into manageable chunks.

1. **Was it a breach of confidentiality to broadcast a private meeting over the radio?** Yes it most certainly was. Unless both parties expected this meeting to be public, its a huge violation. It's also really hard to imagine how it could have been done accidentally. Someone screwed up badly.
2. **Was it a breach of confidentiality for you to listen to this meeting?** Yes. When you realized it was a private meeting you should have stopped listening, turned off the radio if that was feasible. On the other hand it's hard to imagine what you could have done if you were supposed to be listening to that channel for other purposes.
3. **Was it a breach of confidentiality to discuss the meeting?** Yes. It is also a breach if you pass on any information you learned there. If your co-worker wants to discuss the meeting with you that's another matter, just as he could have discussed it with you if you hadn't overheard it. Obviously confidentiality of anyone else in the meeting, and company confidentiality, also has to be respected.

Comment: Excellent point that the initial breach of broadcasting possibly doesn't negate the breach of listening and certainly does negate discussing it.

Comment: There are literally no laws for tapping into uncrypted communication over walkie talkie.  It is part of public domain.  Wire tapping laws are very specific to the telephone and crypted services communication.  Walkie talkiies is the same as truckers using CBs - it is not illegal to overhear conversations in these domains.  Now as for company policy it might be something.

Comment: @blankip is correct.  You did nothing illegal (in the U.S., anyway) by listening to an unencrypted transmission.  Your admins, however, may have, depending on your jurisdiction.

Comment: Whether what he did was right or wrong, by keeping quiet about it the thread starter would have saved himself a lot of trouble. And that trouble was foreseeable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, what you did was wrong, even though the person you discussed it with was in the meeting. Think how you would have felt if it had been you and someone else outside the meeting made a comment on what happened. It is painful enough to be disciplined at work; to find out everyone else knows about it makes it that much more painful. It is a severe violation of privacy.

Disciplinary meetings are by their very nature considered private and **all employees in all businesses** are expected to know that. You should have known you had no business listening. You should have known that when you heard something you shouldn't have that you had a duty to bury that as deeply as possible and never mention it.

If it happens again, speak up immediately and tell them they are broadcasting before you hear anything you shouldn't. If you can't avoid hearing it, then never mention it to anybody including people outside the office. Because you are on probation for this, you need to be extra careful now.